# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzf" on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

I'm getting this strange error

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzf" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dancam.chords-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.dancam.chords-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>                                                                          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>                                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zzeU(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfh.zza(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                          at dancam.com.chords.Drawer.onCreate(Drawer.java:105) 
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684) 
>                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2637) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

at Drawer, line 105

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn");
```

It's the first time I see this error and searching on Google I couldn't even find people talking about it.

Does any of you know why this happens and how to fix it?

**MORE INFO:**

After implemented the library I had to modify my `build.gradle` and add

```
defaultConfig {
 ...
 multiDexEnabled true
}

dataBinding {
 enabled = true
}
```

**can this changes have something to do with the error?**

Comment: Have you added the dependencies in build.gradle file for Ads?

Comment: @mthakuri sure I did, it used to work before adding this library

Comment: Can you uninstall the app from device or simulator and then rerun with clean build? And I hope you have followed mutidex(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) integration and dependencies properly.

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/10 . Please also go through this, the issue can be due to different version of Play Service on device and the one you are compiling your app with.

Comment: I have read about multidex, I read that it could slow down the app significantly. is there a way to avoid using it?

Comment: Slow your build process not your app. Yes you can avoid by not using too many dependencies :D. Now a days things are getting better as far as build process is concern but yes it need to go a long way to be considered fast.

Comment: I managed to fix that. the multiDex is still enabled. It wasn't that causing the error. Just a stupid inattention of mine. Thank you for the help and advice

Comment: Can you mention what you missed? Will be helpful to others

Comment: @mthakuri I already answered my own question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this. I implemented firebase in my app like this

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
```

the mismatch of version among this dependencies caused the app to crash. changing the last dependency to

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
```

fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is occurring because `google-play-services.jar` is not located on path. is you added already and add jar into class path or proper location of jar file path. and if you are not use this then download jar and add into class path. you can download from bellow link:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgoogleplayservicesjar.htm

if you are use maven project you can use bellow dependency  :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: that's strange before implementing the library everything was working fine. Could this be because I enabled databinding? That's the only thing I changed. I also enabled multiDexEnabled actually

Comment: I tried reinstalling the Google Play services but the error is still there

Comment: then try this... right click on project and click on properties.  "Properties for " panel will open. go to Java Build Path -> Order and Export . From the list below uncheck the box next to "Android Dependencies". Finally clean your project and run.